# Jump from section 1.1 to section 1.3 in the ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

The `\tableofcontents` command shows sections enumerated accordingly. Suppose I am on Chapter 1, and say I have subsections as 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,.... and so on. Suppose I don't have section 1.2 and I want `\tableofcontents` to directly show subsections 1.1 and 1.3 and .... what should I do?

Comment: `\refstepcounter{section}` before using the second section? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `\stepcounter{section}` before the 2nd section that should be numbered.

`\refstepcounter{section}` is also possible, but a label is useless here, so `\refstepcounter` is not really needed!

Also possible: `\setcounter{section}{2}`

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}

\section{First section 1.1}


\stepcounter{section}
\section{Second section, but is 1.3}

\section{Third section, but will be numbered 1.4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to jump from 1.1 to 1.5 then 1.6,1.7 and so on??

Comment: @S.C. Well, that's the same. You asked for `1.1` to `1.3.`. How should I know that you want to have more of this?

Comment: That's the same means?? What are the commands for jumping from `1.1` to `1.5`??

Comment: Yup. I inserted one more \setcounter command and it worked :) thanks

Comment: @S.C. A better solution requires some clue why there are 'spurious' jumps

Answer (score 1):

Tell LaTeX how many sections you want to skip:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}

\section{Will be 1.1}

\addtocounter{section}{1} % skip one section

\section{Will be 1.3}

\addtocounter{section}{9} % skip 9 sections

\section{Will be 1.13}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the code. Shows Headling and toc]

Alternatively, tell LaTeX what number the next section should have. With this you have perhaps more flexibility; the first argument is the counter (`chapter`, `section`, `subsection` and so on), the second argument is the next value the counter should have.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\nextnumber}[2]{%
  \setcounter{#1}{#2}%
  \addtocounter{#1}{-1}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}

\section{Will be 1.1}

\nextnumber{section}{3}

\section{Will be 1.3}

\nextnumber{section}{13}

\section{Will be 1.13}

\end{document}
```